# Most efficient way of determining in which range a number is?

Tags: php

My application generates a random integer between 0 and 1000.

I have 5 ranges: `0-50`, `51-250`, `251-500`, `501-700`, `701-1000`. (Note that the range sizes are not equal.)

I will call these ranges: "0","50","250","500","700", respectively (will store those names in my database).

I know that i could do the following:

```
if ($number > 700 && $number <=1000)
       $num_range='700';

else if...
```

... and so on.

But is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Thanks a lot in advance. Regards

Comment: correct your ranges. one number can not be in 2 ranges. make it 0-49, 50-249, 500-699, 700-1000

Comment: Yes thanks for making me notice. Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize [`elseif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) efficiently:

```php
if($number <= 50)
    $num_range='0';
elseif($number <= 250)
    $num_range='50';
elseif($number <= 500)
    $num_range='250';
elseif($number <= 700)
    $num_range='500';
elseif($number <= 1000)
    $num_range='700';
...
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for your response. The else if makes it efficient indeed. Regards

Comment: wouldn't `switch` be a little more efficient, processor wise?

Comment: @SableFoste how would you use `switch` for a range?

Comment: @Neal, if you replace the `if` and `elseif`s with `case`, and use the `break` within each function, it should flow with the same logic as you have outlined.  `switch` evaluates in order of listing and stops at `break`.

Comment: @SableFoste elseif won't continue if it find a condition that matches, either.

Comment: @Neal, I agree that your solution works, I was just demonstrating that a switch element would work for a range as well.  I am not sure which makes the most efficient use of the processor, though, based upon sachleen's comment.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ranges = array(0,50,250,500,700,1000....);  
$number = ....;

foreach($ranges as $range){
 if ($number>$range)
     continue;
 else 
     return prev($ranges);
}
```

Comment: Why not `if($number < $range) return prev($range);`?

Comment: @Neal voodoo's answer and your comment are both great solutions if OP wants the code to be more flexible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It seems both solutions are viable. Regards

Answer (score 4):

```
$startPoints = array(700, 500, 250, 50);

$num_range = 0;
foreach ($startPoints as $from) {
    if ($number >= $from) {
        $num_range = $from;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$range[0] = range(0, 49);
$range[50] = range(50, 249);
$range[250] = range(250, 499);
....
```

then do:

```
foreach($range as $r => $vals){
    if(in_array($number, $vals)){
        echo "Number is in range: $r";
    } 
}
```